# how to remove404 not found in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to install WP on a website and I am having issues. I have downloaded the latest version and have installed WP on several site in the past. I also have created a theme and know my way around WP but the issue is installing.

I upload all of WP files up to the directory:

http://www.jaaper.com/jobs/submit-resume/ and this is what I get:

> Not Found
> The requested URL /cgi-bin(1)/index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I do not understand what it is? I have worked with php and have the database up and running. This is a first for me...

Comment: btw, for me the url is working fine.

Comment: so what's the solution for change this

Comment: when you click somewhere like activity then errer occured

Comment: Edit the content of your .htaccess file in the question

Comment: Homepage works fine... /jobs/. Issue is with sub links... Is it problem with activate PHP in server??? [reffered here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-error-17)

Comment: yes the issue is with its sublinks

Comment: i don't know how to activate php in server

Comment: PHP is working, otherwise you wouldn't even see the wordpress start page. Show your .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys I found my Solution there have an .htaccess file problem change the foldere path and got the result

Comment: please add the content of the fixed htaccess file and describe what you changed so others in the future can benefit from your answer